# How to use second PC as extended monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have 2 PC's (notebook). Both have Windows 7 32bit. They are cross connected with LAN cable.

**How to use *PC 2* as extended monitor of *PC 1* ?**

I want to achieve same effect as I would connect external LCD to PC 1.

[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) requires LAN router/switcher, I only have cross LAN connection.

Comment: Well, can't you just use a Cross Over cable and statically assign IP addresses and then use MaxiVista?

Comment: It appears the gent below has answered the question, but I would also suggest Synergy as a possible program for this as well. I have used it for a while and it does very well.

Answer (score 1):

As you only have 2 PCs, and if your only limitation with MaxiVista is obtaining IP connectivity between the two PCs, you don't need a LAN router or a switch, but only a [Ethernet cross-over cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) between the PCs.  (You can purchase one of these from your favorite computer retailer if you don't have one or don't want to make your own.)

Since you won't have a DHCP server, you will either need to manually assign IP addresses on each PC in the same subnet, or use the [auto configuration addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Address_autoconfiguration) (will take a few minutes for the DHCP query attempts to timeout) - which will result in `169.254.*.*` addresses on each.

Comment: Note that with modern network cards [you won’t even need a crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX)