# Can I use my two laptops as dual monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use second PC as extended monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/372723/how-to-use-second-pc-as-extended-monitor)

I have [Lenovo Y470](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/ww/pdf/Y470_Datasheet_US.pdf) [Core i7 quad core ] with windows 7 in it and macbook pro [ core i7 ]. Both of these are on same wifi network. I want to use macbook pro as another screen for lenovo. Consider that I don't have admin rights on macbook pro, that says I can't install anything on that. *But don't limit your answer because of this problem. if required I will manage to install any software on that*

Can I somehow share the macbook pro screen with my lenovo laptop?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I somehow share the macbook pro screen with my lenovo laptop?

Your Macbook Pro only has Video Out port.  What you want is not possible.  The display your Macbook Pro is using cannot be connected or redirected to another computer.

**What you want to do is not possible.**

Comment: OK then if it is having video out port, then can I use my lenovo laptop display as secondary monitor ?

Comment: @Rakesh - Your laptop's display CANNOT be hooked up to another computer.  What you want to do is not possible.