# How to make another pc monitor an external monior without cable?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop and a desktop (with monitor). I have used my desktop monitor as an external monitor.

Now the HDMI port on my laptop is broken.

***So my question is basicly how to share keybord, clipboard and mouse on other monitor.***

Is there any way to connect remotely to my desktop and to use my desktop monitor as an external monitor?

- Both computers run on Windows.
- With Remote Desktop I can only see the desktop screen on my laptop when my desktop screen is off.
- With TeamViewer both screens are on but I have to have Desktop screen in focus in order to control it. Although I have activated TeamViewer to accept LAN Connections there is a huge lag.

Comment: Your current workaround method honestly is the work around method to actually hooking a monitor to the device.  You have excluded two of your best options it seems.  Sounds like you should get the HDMI port repaired, or use another RDC client, over a lan connection.

Comment: related/duplicates?: [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/q/15254/172747) and [How to use second PC as extended monitor](http://superuser.com/q/372723/172747)

Comment: yes it is duplicate but it was asked 5 years ago. And that solutions dont work on windows 8.1

Comment: Have you considered a USB to HDMI adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I am shure that there are other software like this. But I didnt need RDC to transfer video and use Internet or Lan speed, Because the second monitor is right next to me.

So, http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/ or synergy (but I could not test it because there is no trial)

*I have tested it and it works with windows 8.1, 7 and Vista, there is and MAC version also and it is free for personal use.*

Comment: Synergy is free. 'Mouse without borders' is another free alternative.

Comment: https://synergy-project.org/purchase/faq/ are you shure ? You can download the source code from our project's GitHub account and compile it yourself.

Comment: synergy WAS free, but is no longer...unless you google search for it instead of getting it directly from their website.  There's some sites out there that have archives of fairly recent versions.  Also, synergy allows you to remotely control **another computer**'s mouse and keyboard...not display local video on that remote machine's monitor